# Intercept the destroy method in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to log some information when the user deletes things on my system.

The premise is simple, if I delete it I'll record it in the log_delete table.

I know it's possible to do this using `before_destroy`, however, I would like the implementation to be transparent, and not need to add `before_destroy` to every model.

That way the developer doesn't have to worry about putting this in if he creates a new model.

Is there any way to use something like `before_destroy` for all models?

Comment: Hierarchy or composition would be a good way to go. How do you feel about it? Or you can monkey patch the `ApplicationRecord`, which all models inherit from

Comment: The solution provided by user "mu is too short" worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have an `ApplicationRecord` like this:

```
class ApplicationRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  # Maybe some other stuff...
end
```

as a base class for all your ActiveRecord models.

You could put a `before_destroy` there and then the callback can pull whatever information out of `self` and `self.class` that it needs to log.

`ApplicationRecord` has been standard practice since, AFAIK, Rails 5 so it should be in place and if it isn't, you really should add one.

---

Alternatively you could use a database trigger and let the database take care of it. I tend to think a trigger is where this sort of thing belongs and has the benefit of being a lot harder to get around (either intentionally or accidentally). On the downside, this requires a small amount of database-specific coding but that's nearly impossible to avoid in any non-trivial application.

Comment: If you're on pre Rails 5 version you either need to manually change all your generated models to inherit from ApplicationRecord or set up a custom template. But then again Rails 4 is veeery old.

Comment: @max Veeeery old as in 2016 which is forever ago. If someone is still using it then they have bigger problems on their hands than modifying every model or adding a custom template.